# How to get informed about system update is available

Tags: notifications, big-sur, apple-silicon, auto-update

[image]I'm running mac book air with M1 chip. I have it more than one time that I get information about system update with security fix, reading heise-news.
I have set everything at automatic-update. However, I never get a notification. What must I do to fix this?